# PHP Form conditional statement

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I have a contact form with existing captcha. I created the form and combined the upload feature in it. Problem is when i tried to submit the form without captcha it doesn't show the js alert or the invalid captcha alert but when i tried to attach an image then submit the form without captcha, it is submitted.. The code's a mess right now. Can anyone please check out the conditional statments and see if you can help me fix this? I'm not good in php.

this is my mail.php

```
        <?php
if($_SESSION["captcha"] == $_POST["captcha"]) {

  //if($_SESSION["captcha"] == $_POST["captcha"]) {

   // we'll begin by assigning the To address and message subject
   $to="myemail@gmail.com";

   $subject="E-mail with attachment";

   // get the sender's name and email address
   // we'll just plug them a variable to be used later
   $from = stripslashes($_POST['fromname'])."<".stripslashes($_POST['fromemail']).">";

   // generate a random string to be used as the boundary marker
   $mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";

   // store the file information to variables for easier access
   $tmp_name = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
   $type = $_FILES['filename']['type'];

   $size = $_FILES['filename']['size'];

   // here we'll hard code a text message
   // again, in reality, you'll normally get this from the form submission
   $message = 'Message from '.$_REQUEST['name'].'


    Full Name: '.$_REQUEST['name'].'
    Address: '.$_REQUEST['address'].'
    Contact Number: '.$_REQUEST['contact'].'
    Email: '.$_REQUEST['email'].'
    How do you come to know about us: '.$_REQUEST['type'].'
    Car Make: '.$_REQUEST['make'].'
    Car Model: '.$_REQUEST['model'].'
    Year: '.$_REQUEST['year'].'
    Registration: '.$_REQUEST['registration'].'
    Comment: '.$_REQUEST['comments'].'
   ';

   // if the upload succeded, the file will exist
   if (file_exists($tmp_name)){

      // check to make sure that it is an uploaded file and not a system file
      if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name)){

         // open the file for a binary read
         $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');

         // read the file content into a variable
         $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));

         // close the file
         fclose($file);

         // now we encode it and split it into acceptable length lines
         $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
     }

      // now we'll build the message headers
      $headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
         "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
         "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
         " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

      // next, we'll build the message body
      // note that we insert two dashes in front of the
      // MIME boundary when we use it
      $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
         "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
         "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
         "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
         $message . "\n\n";

      // now we'll insert a boundary to indicate we're starting the attachment
      // we have to specify the content type, file name, and disposition as
      // an attachment, then add the file content and set another boundary to
      // indicate that the end of the file has been reached
      $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
         "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
         " name=\"{$name}\"\n" .
         //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
         //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
         "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
         $data . "\n\n" .
         "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

      // now we just send the message
      if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        echo "<script>alert('Your details has been Sent Successfully, we shall revert back to you shortly!!!');</script>";
        echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
      } else {
         echo "<script>alert('Sending Failed');</script>";
         echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
   } }
} else {
    echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php?cap=invalid';</script>";
}
?>
```

Here's the form:

```
    <div class="quote-wrap left">
<form name="quoteForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="mail.php" onsubmit="return validateQuoteForm();">
<div class="quote-table left liquid-size">
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle" style="padding-bottom:0px;"><?php $qerror ?></td>
    </tr>                                               
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle" style="padding-bottom:0px; color:#FF0000;"><h3><?php $captcha_stat?></h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left">
        <input type="text" name="make" placeholder="Make:" class="input-field" value="$make" />
        <span class="required">*</span> 
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left">
        <input type="text" name="model" placeholder="Model:" class="input-field" value="$model" /><span class="required">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left">
        <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="Year:" class="input-field" value="$year"/>
        <span class="required">*</span>                                                  
    </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left">
        <input type="text" name="registration" placeholder="Registration:" class="input-field" value="$registration" /><span class="required">*</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="quote-table left liquid-size">
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left">
        <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Full Address:" class="input-field" value="$address" /><span class="required">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name:" class="input-field"  value="$name"/><span class="required">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left">
        <input type="text" name="contact" placeholder="Contact No:" class="input-field"  value="$contact"/><span class="required">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email:" class="input-field" value="$email" /><span class="required">*</span></td>
    </tr>                                           
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left">How do you come to know about Us?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left">
        <select class="quotable-select" name="type">
        <option value="Google search">Google search</option>
        <option value="Yahoo search">Yahoo search</option>
        <option value="Bing search">Bing search</option>
        <option value="Hotfrog">Hotfrog</option>
        <option value="Local Newspaper">Local Newspaper</option>
        <option value="Magazine">Magazine</option>
        <option value="Returning Customer">Returning Customer</option>
        <option value="Heard about us">Heard about us</option>
        <option value="Saw us on the road">Saw us on the road</option>                                      
        <option value="Referral">Referral</option>
        <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
        <option value="Trademe">Trademe</option>
        <option value="Yellow Online">Yellow Online</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="left" class="required" valign="middle">
        <span class="required">Note: Image must not be greater than 1MB.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left" wid>
            Attach Photos:&nbsp;&nbsp; 
            <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="filename" border="0" />  
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="middle" align="left">
            <textarea class="quote-txtarea" placeholder="Comments:" name="comments" rows="3" cols="22">$comments</textarea>   
        </td>
    </tr>                                               
    <tr>                                                    
        <td valign="top" >
            <img src="captcha.php" name="captcha" id="captcha" style="padding: 0px;  margin: 0 0 -4px;" />
            <input class="input" type="text" name="captcha" style="width:100px; height: 20px; padding: 0px;" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit_quote" class="submit" value="Submit" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say "it's not validating", what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error on your final `echo` line, remember to end the line with a semicolon. You don't give much information as to what you mean about it not validating – so I'm only guessing here – but you're using `@mail`. The `@` symbol will suppress errors.

So try removing the `@` symbol to see if you get any more descriptive errors, and also turn on error reporting by adding this line near the start:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also, you won't be seeing an error all the time, because you don't cover every possible condition. This is a simplification of your code:

```
 <?php
    if($_SESSION["captcha"] == $_POST["captcha"]) {
        if (file_exists($tmp_name)){
            if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
                // Success
            } else {
                // Send failed
            } 
        } // <-- Add an else clause here!
    } else {
        // Invalid
    }
?>
```

So you don't do anything if `file_exists` returns false. Add an else clause that returns a message:

Comment: I'd like to ask for help. as you can see when you try to submit the form it's not really working as I want it to work. If a user submits the form and inputs wrong captcha it should say Invalid captcha if it's successful, then it should say 

echo "<script>alert('Your details has been Sent Successfully, we shall revert back to you shortly!!!');</script>";
echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php';</script>";

but with the upload feature now it's a mess.

Comment: Like I said, you're missing a semicolon on line 104.

Comment: I added the semicolon on the form. can you please check again on the link? when you click on submit it's not showing the javascript alert.

Comment: Updated answer. You don't cover every possibility.